# Flutter: Exit a Firestore transaction if conditions not met

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In the following Firestore transaction, the following exception occurs if the condition (someNumber < 2) is not met:

**The Exception:**

> PlatformException (PlatformException(9, Transaction failed all retries.: Every document read in a transaction must also be written in that transaction., null))

**The transaction:**

```
_myFunction({@required docId,}) {
  try {
  final DocumentReference docRef = Firestore.instance.collection('collection').document(docId);
  Firestore.instance.runTransaction(
    (tx) async { 
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await tx.get(docRef);
      var someNumber = snapshot['someNumber'] ?? 0;
        if (snapshot.exists && someNumber < 2) {
          await tx.update(
            docRef,
              {
              'someNumber': FieldValue.increment(1),
              },
            );
        } else {
          print("someNumber exceeded");
          return;
        }
      },
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

The transaction works correctly if *someNumber* is less than 2. This variable needs to be read inside the transaction as two users could potentially update the value at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also had this error. As per [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/LfD_YEnGVu4) it looks like it's a known limitation (though this discussion started almost 2 years ago, nothing seems to be changed yet):

> This is unfortunately a known limitation in the client SDKs at this time (hopefully resolved before GA).  The clients use optimistic concurrency for transactions (where there's no locking, and instead the client says, "as a precondition for my write, make sure the document version is still X", where X is whatever version the client read during the transaction).  Currently there's no way for the client to say "also make sure this other document that I'm not writing is still version Y."  We will be adding this ability and changing the client SDKs to allow reading documents without modifying them, but I don't have a definite timeline for that.